# MultipartHttpServletRequest BeanInstantiationException root cause java.lang.InstantiationException

Tags: spring

I am uploading an image from client to browser using MultipartHttpServletRequest

Therefore I downloaded the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And added in bean using Java Based configuration

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;
    }
```

Here is my Request Mapping Method for uploading a file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/ModifyUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ServiceResponse modifyUser(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,HttpServlet response)
    {
        Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();

        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        String firstName=request.getParameter("fname");
        String lastName=request.getParameter("lname");
        String password=request.getParameter("pass");
        String email=request.getParameter("email");

        MultipartFile multipartFileImage = request.getFile(itr.next());

        try {
            File saveImage = new File("C://"+"("+id+")"+multipartFileImage.getOriginalFilename());

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response(abc(user));
    }
```

But I when I hit the above `@RequestMapping` I am getting

> SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Fiserv] threw
>   exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet]: Is it an abstract
>   class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException] with
>   root cause  java.lang.InstantiationException  at
>   sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Post the full stacktrace not a snippet.

Comment: Posted please look what could be the issue

Comment: Why do you have `HttpServlet` as the second argument? You probably want the `HttpServletResponse` instead. Although you aren't appearing to be using it at all, so I would simply remove it.

Comment: yes but it doesn't resolve my problem and I guess it doesn't have any effect on it

Comment: @Plootus could you edit your question to point out what is your current problem?

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum I resolved the complete problem It was mandatory to use HttpServletResponse  I dont know the reason but Its working now you can update it as answer I will accept

Comment: @d4widk I was having problem in updating user information where I am sending user form data using ajax call and receiving whole data MultipartHttpServletRequest therefore I was getting some error but I solved it you can see the above conversation

Comment: @Plootus great to know that you have solved your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use [`HttpServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) as a method argument as that is now going to be interpreted as a regular object and Spring will try to instantiate it. Spring creates an instance because it isn't one of the [supported arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods). It is now interpreted as a *Any other object* (last entry in the table). It isn't a simply object (`String`, `int` etc.) so it will try to construct an instance. Creating an instance will fail as the `HttpServlet` isn't meant to be used like that.

You probably want to use the [`HttpServletResponse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) instead. However as you aren't using that argument in the method at all you are probably better of by removing it.

Comment: can you help me with this part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650966/upload-a-file-using-commons-multiparthttpservlet-resolver